# Converting C program to C++ with lot of char* and unsigned char conversion errors

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I need to use methods described in [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) and [RFC1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321), but am getting problems about converting C to C++. Mostly I have problem with a parameter is defined as `unsigned char` but argument is a `char*` variable. 
I can solve errors with `reinterpret_cast` but thought there would be a better way, because there is lot of changes need to be done.

For example in the following line in `md5c.c` variable `pszUserName` is declared as char*, if the variable changed to `unsigned char*`, then `strlen` got errors:

```
IN char * pszUserName,
...
MD5Update(&Md5Ctx, pszUserName, strlen(pszUserName));
```

Declaration of MD5Update

```
void MD5Update (
    MD5_CTX *context,                                        /* context */
    unsigned char *input,                                /* input block */
    unsigned int inputLen                      /* length of input block */
)
{
...
}
```

I got this error in the first place:

```
../Dig/digcalc.cpp: In function ‘void DigestCalcHA1(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*)’:
../Dig/digcalc.cpp:44:58: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’ [-fpermissive]
       MD5Update(&Md5Ctx, pszUserName, strlen(pszUserName));
```

There is also a nice copy in [Github](https://github.com/richarddurbin/acedb/blob/master/wmd5/md5c.c)

Comment: You could use the compiler flag `-Wno-pointer-sign` to suppress these messages

Comment: Use `vector<unsigned char>`, which solves issues with `strlen()` not working. Anyhow, I can guess what your problem is, even though the description is a bit vague, but in order to propose a fix, I'd need a much wider view on what you are doing. Probably, that scope would be too wide to post here.

Comment: suggest using 'reference' parameters rather than pointer parameters

Comment: @user3629249, May you please provide me an example?

Comment: If you know C++ then you know about `&` after a parameter name in a function signature.   Such a `&` allows the called function the access the original data in the calling function without having to pass the address nor having to us `*` to dereference an address pointer.  That is the simple explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are *types incompatible* with each other. The code:

```
MD5Update(&Md5Ctx, pszUserName, strlen(pszUserName));
```

"should" be:

```
MD5Update(&Md5Ctx, (char *)pszUserName, strlen(pszUserName));
```

---

However, in my opinion, this is all rather annoying. `MD5Update` works equally well on `char` as `unsigned char`; we shouldn't have to make the code less readable for no real reason.

On existing codebases that use `char *` and `unsigned char *` interchangeably like this, I enable the compiler flag `-Wno-pointer-sign` and don't feel bad about it.   It keeps the code more readable and the compiler behaves as if there were a cast.

Comment: I got:  `command line option ‘-Wno-pointer-sign’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++`

Comment: @SAMPro Oh. You should not try to "compile C as C++" either.  Compile the C files as C.  When writing new C++ code, follow the rules.

Comment: but all my effort is to convert that code to C++ as title clearly indicated.

Comment: I ran into this extension [when I was writing my strict aliasing article the other day](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8#a12) also [see this tweet](https://twitter.com/kwalfridsson/status/957709139882446848)